# Retaining task queues on deploying a new version

Tags: google-app-engine, upgrade, task-queue

For Google App Engine apps, are task queues cleared when you deploy a new version of your app?

If the queues are cleared, what's the best strategy for persisting tasks across versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very simple answer and you will be very happy with it: NO!